# Prove that every positive rational number can be written in factorial base

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, factorial

> Prove that for every $n \in \Bbb Q^{+}$, $\exists ! k \in \Bbb Z^{+}$ and a sequence of non-negative integers $\{a_m\}$ such that $a_1 \geq 0, a_k > 0$ and $0 \leq a_j < j, \forall j: \, 1 < j \leq k$ so that $n = \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{a_j}{j!}$

Proving that it is unique is not a real problem, but proving that a representation exists is hard. My approach is to show that the sequence $b_1 = n$ and $b_j = b_{j-1} - \frac{\lfloor b_{j-1}(j-1)! \rfloor}{(j-1)!}$ is such that $b_k = 0$ for some k; then I’ll show it’s unique: but I couldn’t advance. How’d I prove it?

Comment: If it is required that $0\leq a_1<1$, then $\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{a_j}{j!}\leq \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{(j-1)!}<e$. We won't be able to represent all non-negative rationals.

Comment: It’s not required.

Comment: Start with $n=\frac ab$.  Since there is no upper bound on $a_k$, just choose $k$ such that $b\,|\,k!$, write $k!=b\times c$ and then take $a_k=a\times c$, with all the other $a_j=0$.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: @lulu In fact, I forgot to write that $a_k < k$

Comment: @LucasHenrique what do you mean $n\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ and then $a_n$?

Comment: Lol, my bad. I’m a bit sleepy and writing through my smartphone so things are a bit nonsense right now. I’m gonna fix it.

Comment: It looks like an interesting question.  Worth clearing up the stray details.  Maybe include your proof of uniqueness?

Comment: You can go backwards instead. Take a non-negative rational $p/q$.  Let $k!$ be the smallest factorial that is divisible by $q$. then $k!p/q$ is an integer. Define $a_k$ to be the remainder of this number after division by $k$. Subtract $a_k$ and divide by $k$. Define $a_{k-1}$ to be the remainder of the result after division by $k-1$ ... Eventually you only need to divide by $1$, at that point just take $a_1$ to be equal to the integer that remains. Uniqueness comes from the uniqueness of the Euclidean division.

Comment: good one, @noodlesGroup! Post the answer formally and I’ll accept it as correct. thanks :)

Comment: Let $S(0)=a_0$ be the largest integer not exceeding $n$. Recursively for $j\geq 0$ let $a_{j+1}$ be the largest  non-negative integer $v$ such that $v/(j+1)!+S(j)\leq n.$  Use induction on $j$ to show that $v<n+1$, ... And conclude that  $n=\lim_{j\to \infty}S(j).$ Now $a_j\ne 0$ for only finitely many $j,$ otherwise $j!n\not \in \Bbb N$ for any $ j.$

Comment: My previous comment applies verbatim for any $n\in \Bbb R$ except for the last sentence (where it should have said "$ j!n\not \in \Bbb Z$")  so until you get to that part  you do not need to consider whether or not $0\leq n\in \Bbb Q.$